# In Overwatch, is ultimate charge rate affected by damage boosts?

Tags: overwatch

Many characters in the game charge up their ultimate abilities by dealing damage to enemies. Abilities such as Mercy's Caduceus Staff, Orisa's Supercharger and Ana's Nano Boost grant a % increase to the damage output of characters.

Does this amplified damage affect the ultimate-charging speed of the target heroes in any way? i.e. will Symmetra get more charge if her orb hits an enemy while damage-amped, rather than not?

Comment: It would make sense, more damage done, after your ultimate charges (unless that has changed)

Comment: Side note: Mercy gets ult charge for damage her allies do to enemies while being damage boosted.

Comment: Do you still miss any information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Gamepedia](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Ultimate_ability) the damage boost also means a higher charging rate for the ultimate.

Ultimate charge is gained in the following ways:

- Heroes gain 5 charge every second.
- Heroes gain 1 charge for every 1 point of damage done.
     Damage done to barriers does not generate ultimate charge.
- Heroes gain 1 charge for every 1 point of self-healing done.
- Soldier: 76 gains 1 charge for every 1 point of healing.
- Lúcio gains 19 charge for every 15 healing.
- Mercy gains 4 charge for every 5 healing and 2 charge for every 3 damage done by the target of her damage boost.
- Zenyatta gains 33 charge for every 25 healing.
- Heroes do not gain any charge while their Ultimate is active.

  - The only exceptions to this rule are Tracer and Hanzo, who can gain charge while the Ultimate is active, although damage dealt    by the Ultimate won't count, and D.Va, whose Ultimate Call Mech    becomes fully charged after using Self-Destruct.

Comment: So by that logic, Orisa wouldn't gain Ult charge from damage boosted by the supercharger (being her ult), but her teammates would be dealing more damage, so would gain ult faster?

Comment: As far as the information from gamepedia are correct, you are aswell.